# PHP, JS, and Google Maps API - Getting blank canvas when passing center values a PHP value

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been doing some work with implementing Google Maps into a web app and I am having some trouble passing the PHP values to the Google Maps API JS functions.

The goal is to have a map that is centered on a point that is determined by extracting a longitude and latitude by geocoding (using the geocode function of the Maps API) a input from a form on a previous page and binding those values to PHP variables that are passed to the Maps JS functions later down the road. So far my code is as follows:

```
<?php 

    $array_of_stuff = array_values(geocode($_SESSION['address']));  

    $longitude = $array_of_stuff[0];
    $latitude = $array_of_stuff[1];
?>

  echo '<div id="map"></div>';

?>

<script>

  function initMap() 
  {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
    var mapOptions = 
    {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(<?php echo $latitude ?>), parseFloat(<?php echo $longitude ?>)),
  zoom: 5
};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  }

</script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Whatchalookingfor&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Some things worth noting are firstly, the $_SESSION['address'] variable is a variable that is passed from a form that is on the previous page to the map output page which is where the above code is from.

Secondly, that session variable is passed to a geocode function which I have included in a function file that is included on every page of the app. the function basically makes a call to the google maps geocode link and returns an array including latitude and longitude. I then bind this to a working array using the array_values function and extract the longitude and latitude as separate variables.

The trouble becomes in passing these variables to the initMap() function that outputs the map. I left off with the parseFloat() idea which I will get to in a second, but here are all the things I have tried up to this point:

simply echoing the values as in

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude ?>, <?php echo $longitude ?>),
```

making center not a latLang object but rather hard coding the values as in

```
center: {<?php echo $latitude ?>,<?php echo $longitude ?>},
```

Then I started to do some reading and some sites reccomend using the parse float method. I tried using that method but when I view source on the page it still shows the parseFloat() function call with the PHP value in there such as

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat('12.345678'), ...)
```

In fact in all cases it seems like the number is in the JS source code it is just not parsed correctly for some reason.

Being that my JS skills are not so keen, I don't know if the parse float function should just parse out a number or still show the function declaration.

I have also tried encoding both float values using json_encode() and that still had no luck if I recall correctly.

So needless to say I am stuck. I get a brown blank canvas with "map" and "satellite" buttons in the upper left corner so I feel like the map is being generated, it's just a matter of it not centering properly which is the whole reason I am here. I don't get any warnings in the javascript console in chrome, and I don't get any errors in the PHP error log.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be down to the format of the lat/lng values - can you show examples of them as the following code worked ok when used with predefined lat/lng values rather than from a lookup to the google api.

```
<?php
    /*
    $a = array_values( geocode( $_SESSION['address'] ) );  
    $longitude = $a[0];
    $latitude = $a[1];
    */

    /* For testing I used these coordinates */
    $latitude=52.4223005;
    $longitude=-1.4876417;

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>google maps app</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>

            /* -- how do these appear in source code view? -- */
            <?php
                echo "
                var lat={$latitude};
                var lng={$longitude};";
            ?>

            function initMap() {
                var options = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( lat.toFixed(10), lng.toFixed(10) ),
                    zoom: 5
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );

            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIKey&callback=initMap"></script>
        <style type='text/css' charset='utf-8'>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Ram. Thanks for getting back to me so quick. As requested we implemented your code block and it looks like in the source code the vars get casted as regular floats which looks like a step in the right direction. Here is the view source dump `code` 

`<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>google maps app</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>

            /* -- how do these appear in source code view? -- */
            
                var lat=52.4223005;
                var lng=-1.4876417;` @RamRaider

Comment: Ram! I found the solution! The Geocode API returns latitude first but I was passing it as if it were longitude. Once I switched the two variables the map loaded perfectly! Thanks for all your help and just figured you might want to know what the answet was :) @RamRaider